# SQL JDBC & Java JUnit Test Failing

Tags: java, sql

I'm trying to run a JUnit test (CreditcardDAOTest) on my class CreditCardDaoImpl. I keep getting the error `"java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2"` but I don't think there are two params. 
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. The error I believe is coming from the `"ps.setLong(1, customerID);"` I'm assuming there should be a `"ps.setLong(x,x);"` but I don't know what it's supposed to be. I tried debugging and it seems like it should be the name entry for my statement :

```
final static String retrieveForCustomerID = 
        "SELECT name = ?, cc_number = ?, exp_date = ?, security_code = ?,  WHERE customerID = ?;";
```

but again I'm just not at all sure. Please know that I have been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm simply looking for guidance.

```
//Method in CreditCardDAOImpl
public CreditCard retrieveForCustomerID(Connection connection, Long customerID) throws SQLException, DAOException 
{
    if (customerID == null ) 
    {
        throw new DAOException("Trying to retrieve credit card with NULL customerID");
    }

    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try 
    {
        ps = connection.prepareStatement(retrieveForCustomerID);
        ps.setLong(1, customerID);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        CreditCard cc = new CreditCard();
        cc.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        cc.setCcNumber(rs.getString("cc_number"));
        cc.setExpDate(rs.getString("exp_date"));
        cc.setSecurityCode(rs.getString("security_code"));
        return cc;
    }
    finally 
    {
    }
}

//Method in CreditCardDAOTest
@Test
public void testRetrieveForCustomerID() throws Exception
{
    DataSource ds = DataSourceManager.getDataSource();
    Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
    CreditCardDAO dao = new CreditCardDaoImpl();

    CreditCard ccard = dao.retrieveForCustomerID(connection, customerID);
    assertNotNull(ccard);
    assertNotNull(ccard.getCcNumber());
    assertNotNull(ccard.getExpDate());
    assertNotNull(ccard.getName());
    assertNotNull(ccard.getSecurityCode());

    connection.close();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean if(!rs.next()) {
   return null;
  }

Comment: First change is to update your query as below and then before using resultSet as rs.`getXXX()` call rs.next(). This [link](http://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/jdbc-preparedstatement-select-like) should help

Comment: That's great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rs.next()` and your query should look like

```
final static String retrieveForCustomerID = 
        "SELECT name, cc_number, exp_date, security_code from TABLE_NAME WHERE customerID = ?"
```

**NOTE:** Replace **TABLE_NAME** in the above query with actual table name.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think you should specify your table name in your query and remove the question marks in the select blocks.

   ```
   SELECT name, cc_number , exp_date, security_code FROM your_table_name WHERE customerID = ?
   ```
2. Prior to execute your query you should send all the details for ? in your query by using

   ```
    ps.setInt(), ps.setLong(), ps.setString().... etc.
   ```
3. After executing the prepared statement and get the result set, you should use

   ```
     rs.next()
   ```

to iterate your resutset.